# On whether reducts and axioms commute.

Tags: model-theory

Consider theories $T$ and $T'$, where $T$ is a subset of $T'$, in the same language $L$. Also, let $L'$ be a subset of the language $L$. We can either take the reduct of $T$ or the reduct of $T'$ with $L'$. Would it be the case that the reduct of $T$ is a subset of the reduct of $T'$?

Comment: Well, with the current Covid-19 crisis they are working from home. So no commuting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is a theory, the reduct of $T$ to the language $L'$ is $T\cap \mathrm{Sent}(L')$, where $\mathrm{Sent}(L')$ is the set of $L'$-sentences.

If $T\subseteq T'$, then $(T\cap \mathrm{Sent}(L'))\subseteq (T'\cap \mathrm{Sent}(L'))$.

(This is just elementary set theory: If $X\subseteq Y$, then for all $Z$, $(X\cap Z)\subseteq (Y\cap Z)$.)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Yes, since the reducts of $T$ and $T'$ are still the same sets, with some of the logical structure removed. Any embedding $\pi: T \to T'$ will still be an embedding between the reducts.</s>

Misread the question. @AlexKruckman's answer is correct.

Comment: $T$ and $T'$ are theories, not models. What is an embedding $T\to T'$?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "the same sets, with some of the logical structure removed". I think you interpreted $T$ and $T'$ to be models...

Comment: @AlexKruckman you're dead right.